# Why does output the for loop in Python the list for three times?

Tags: python, for-loop, output

I am a beginner in Python. I am doing an exercise in which I must apply a discount to the items in the list **prices** and store the results in the list **new_prices**. Why is the output repeated three times? Is there a way to avoid it and get the output just one time?

Thank you in advance

```
prices = [2, 50, 70, 30]
new_prices =[]



for i in prices:
    prices[0] = 2 * 0.8
    prices[1] = 50 * 0.6
    prices[2] = 70 * 0.4
    prices[3] = 30 * 0.6
    new_prices.append(prices)


print(new_prices)


output: [[1.6, 30.0, 28.0, 18.0], [1.6, 30.0, 28.0, 18.0], [1.6, 30.0, 28.0, 18.0], [1.6, 30.0, 28.0, 18.0]]

expected output: [[1.6, 30.0, 28.0, 18.0]
```

Comment: You don't need the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific reason for the problem is that your `for` loop is unnecessary, but it rather looks like what you are really trying to do is something like this, where you have a number of different scale factors to multiply by the different elements of `prices`.

```
prices = [2, 50, 70, 30]

scale_factors = [0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6]

new_prices = []
for price, scale_factor in zip(prices, scale_factors):
    new_prices.append(price * scale_factor)

print(new_prices)
```

Note the use of `zip` to take pairs of elements from `prices` and `scale_factors`.

You can also write this as:

```
new_prices = [price * scale_factor     
              for price, scale_factor in zip(prices, scale_factors)]
```